# ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged when image is changed

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am studying scikit image and I have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3DHy.png) named "unknown.png"

I used "from skimage.color import rgb2hed" to transform the colors:

```
im = io.imread("C:\Users\Gerard\Desktop\Demo\folder\unknown.png")
im_hed = rgb2hed(im)
plt.imshow(im_hed)
plt.show()
```

it gives me a good result showing the [color transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUcaY.jpg). However, when I choose another image, im = io.imread("C:\Users\Gerard\Desktop\Demo\folder\sample_1.png") from the same folder it gives me the following error:

```
ihc_hed = rgb2hed(im)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 1163, in rgb2hed
return separate_stains(rgb, hed_from_rgb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 1255, in separate_stains
stains = np.dot(np.reshape(-np.log(rgb), (-1, 3)), conv_matrix)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 225, in reshape
return reshape(newshape, order=order)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Any advice on this? Any form of standardization so that every time I choose a new image the same error wont pop out again and again? Or is the error dependent of the size of the image? (which makes me believe that there is something wrong with scikit-image?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Does the png file contain an alpha channel in addition to RGB?

Comment: @ M4rtini thank you for this, youde made me realize that I need to convert the png file to RGB only, Thanks so much!!